# How to sort slices in GAE Go

Tags: google-app-engine, sorting, interface, go, slice

I am trying to sort slices. How to this in gae using go?

I have struct

```
type courseData struct {
  Key         *datastore.Key
    FormKey         *datastore.Key
  Selected    bool
  User        string
  Name        string
  Description string
  Date        time.Time
}
```

I would like to sort slice of this entity kind in the Name field.

```
q := datastore.NewQuery("Course")
    var courses []*courseData
    if keys, err := q.GetAll(c, &courses); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    } else {
      for i := range courses {                 
          courses[i].Key = keys[i]
      }                           
    }
```

I tried the

```
Sort(data Interface)
```

but not sure how to use it.
Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
    "time"
)

type Course struct {
    Key         string // *datastore.Key
    FormKey     string // *datastore.Key
    Selected    bool
    User        string
    Name        string
    Description string
    Date        time.Time
}

type Courses []*Course

func (s Courses) Len() int      { return len(s) }
func (s Courses) Swap(i, j int) { s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i] }

type ByName struct{ Courses }

func (s ByName) Less(i, j int) bool { return s.Courses[i].Name < s.Courses[j].Name }

func main() {
    var courses = Courses{
        &Course{Name: "John"},
        &Course{Name: "Peter"},
        &Course{Name: "Jane"},
    }
    sort.Sort(ByName{courses})
    for _, course := range courses {
        fmt.Println(course.Name)
    }
```

Output:

```
Jane
John
Peter
```

`Course` and `Courses` need to be exported for use by the `sort` package.

To avoid making the example dependent on GAE, type `*datastore.Key` was changed to `string`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just ask for the entities in the correct order from the datastore?

```
q := datastore.NewQuery("Course").Order("Name")
```